# Simulation problem in pSpice 9.10

Tags: simulation, rectifier

I just started to use PSpice. I created a rectifier in PSpice 9.10, but somewhere I'm making a mistake and I don't know where.

[image: Circuit]

The output:
[image: Output]

Comment: That 1 MOhm resistor in series with your voltage source also looks out of place. (In addition to Oli's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to do with your measurement relative to ground. The DC voltage appears between either side of R2, and you are measuring from the top of R2 to ground.
To fix this either simply move the ground from the bottom of V3 to the bottom of R2, or take a *differential* measurement between top/bottom of R2.